# Gravity Forms Dropdown Options Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I've added this code to the footer.php file:

```
<div class="footer-email-form-container">
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="26" title="true" description="false"]' ); ?></div>
```

On certain pages that have other gravity forms such as https://dynatrap.com/contact/, the drop down options won't display.

I'm not familiar with JavaScript or JQuery, but is that the issue?

EDIT:
When I click the "Submit" button and the form refreshes, the dropdown options show up.  So is it an AJAX issue maybe?  I'm completely lost at this point.

Answer (score 1):

After much research I discovered there was a plugin causing the issue, Gravity Forms Designer.  Not sure exactly what the problem was but after disabling the plugin the form works correctly!